# Take a List as an Input in socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I want to receive a List as input, Java is showing me no error in:

```
List<String> A;
 ObjectOutputStream ins = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
  ins.writeObject(A);
```

The above code executes without error, however this doesn't:

```
List<String> ls;
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
       in.readObject(ls);
```

If I can send a List<>, why cant I accept it? Any reasons and suggestions for the output code?

Comment: Compiler Error. Expected Object got List<String>!

Comment: @Purushottam: Seems like you got a method signature wrong. Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readObject` doesn't take any parameters. You want:

```
List<String> list = (List<String>) in.readObject();
```

(Of course, this isn't really type-safe, and the compiler should at least raise warnings. How you deal with that is a separate matter.)

Answer (score 3):

[There is no readObject method with input parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29).

You need to cast the readObject to type of the object you are trying to read.

```
List ls=  (List)in.readObject();
```